# Change the saving areas of task CVAT

Tags: docker, image, computer-vision, annotations, cvat

How can I change the scope of saving tasks in CVAT? For example, I want to save tasks on another disk, since images take up a huge amount of memory. Maybe you need to change the path somewhere? Or it can be done through the interface

I don't understand where this can be changed.